# ZF2 - Element in Form not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I don't get it. This my fieldset:

```
<?php
namespace example\Form;

use example\Entity\User;
use example\Entity\Strategy\PasswordStrategy;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class UserFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('user');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
        ));

    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

This my form:

```
<?php
namespace example\Form;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use example\Form\UserFieldset;

class UserForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('user-form');

        $userFieldset = new UserFieldset($objectManager);
        $userFieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);

        $this->add($userFieldset);

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Go',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

my action:

```
public function userAction()
{
    $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    $userForm = new UserForm($objectManager);
    return array(
        'form' => $userForm
    );
}
```

my view:

```
<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('user'));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('id'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

And my error:

No element by the name of [id] found in form

Why? Just the submit field renders fine but as soon as I add the id field I get an error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render using ***FormCollection()***

```
<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('user'));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formCollection($form->get('user'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Or like this

```
<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('user'));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('user')->get("id"));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('user')->get("submit"));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo $this->formRow($form->get('user')->get('id'));
```

You need to get this element through the fieldset.